# add_filter and remove_filter added before and after wp_query

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, wp-query, filters

I have just started with WordPress Development, and found following block of code online (in some tutorial)

```
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {    // posts in the last 30 days
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```

I am not able to understand **why** add_filter and remove_filter are called before and after WP_Query? In what scenario we need to use above kind of pattern?

Answer (score 4):

This was done to restrict the effect of those filters to this one query between both calls.

There are probably other instances of `WP_Query` during page load, and you don’t want to change their results.

Imagine what happens when you do not remove the filter: All later `new WP_Query();` calls would be restricted to a certain date period. All posts from an author, all pages, custom post types … that would really hurt.

You don’t even need the second call, you can remove the filter from the first callback:

```
function filter_where( $where = '' ) 
{
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    // posts in the last 30 days
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
    return $where;
}
```

Comment: first of all, thanks for quick reply. I am quite new to WordPress, can you please explain in bit detail

Comment: @I-M-JM Better now?

Comment: Hmmm, it's much better now.Also liked your suggestion to remove filter in function body itself.